# Не получается логгировать одни сообщения в консоль,а другие в файл

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, логирование

Ребят,может кто-то подскажет.Пишу авто-тесты на Selenium WebDriver на Java.Мне надо чтобы одни сообщения выводило в консоль,а другие писало в файл. В самом коде пишу такое:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(название нашего класса.class);
logger.info(будем писать в консоль)
logger.debug(будем писать в файл)`
```

В файле - log4j properties прописываю такие настройки:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFo,file,stout

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log(изменить)(./logs/logging.log)
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
log4j.appender.stout.threshold=INFO
```

Ну естественно подключаю зависимости через Maven

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Но по факту я могу писать только logger.info, а debug мне недоступно

Comment: `log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log(изменить)(./logs/logging.log)` это так у вас в конфиге и прописано?